# Slow performance cropping large JPEG2000 images with ImageMagick/Jasper

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg2000

I have a 4000x3000, 3.7MB JPEG2000 file that I'm trying to process into cropped tiles. I do this with a command like:

```
convert 486.jp2 -crop 256x256+0+0 -format jpg 486_crop.jpg
```

This command takes 5 seconds to run on a current-model Mac Pro. ImageMagick is using the Jasper library, which I've read is very slow. I just want to make sure I'm not botching the command somehow before I abandon ImageMagick in this application.

Comment: can you provide us your image for us to test?

Comment: http://digital.library.unlv.edu/cgi-bin/showfile.exe?CISOROOT=/LV_Maps&CISOPTR=451

Comment: JP2K is a VERY cpu intensive format, hence why it is not widely adopted yet even tho' it is a great format (and that also supports lossless compression)

Comment: @hexa: JP2K was considered to be CPU-intensive 10 years ago, but modern CPUs should eat it for lunch. Kakadu is much faster, for example.

Comment: You speak as if all computers were quad cores 4ghz machines.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick has poor perf (pretty good results though). You can consider GraphicsMagick instead. A few interesting benchmarks (there is one for the crop option): [GraphicsMagick 1.3.8 vs ImageMagick 6.5.8-10 Benchmark Report](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/benchmarks.html)

Answer (score 0):

On a year old Mac mini (2.53 C2D):

```
$ ls -hn test.jp2
-rw-r--r--  1 501  20    10M Aug 12 23:40 test.jp2

$ time convert test.jp2 -crop 256x256 -format jpg test/%d.jpg

real    0m3.971s
user    0m3.383s
sys     0m0.535s
```

On a current-model quad-core Mac Pro it should run no slower.

I am using a stock version of ImageMagick from ports:

```
$ convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.3-0 2010-08-31 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP OpenCL
```

Also it is **same slow when tiling PNG** or plain JPEG. Seems to me that JPEG2000 isn't the issue here.

Comment: can you provide a link to that image?

Comment: Sorry, the image I linked above is not the same as the one I benchmarked. Still, that's way too slow. :(